# Ошибка загрузки рекламы AdMob в плагине для phonegap/cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, admob, phonegap

Я пишу мобильное приложение используя phonegap. Для монетизации я решил использовать плагин cordova-plugin-admobpro. Для проверки я использовал тестовые id **ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111** для баннера и  **ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712** для межстраничного объявления. Тестовые id работали, но когда я подключил собственные id, реклама перестала загружаться, появилась ошибка 0. Аккаунт в AdMob был создан 2 дня назад, и все вроде уже должно работать.
В androidManifest имеется блок **meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx" android:value="ca-app-pub-xxx~xxx"** с моим app id,  в блоке application. Я попробовал создать новый баннер в моём аккаунте adMob, но это не помогло. Возможно, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой и знает методы её решения.

Android manifest

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.phonegap.helloworld" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.ca-app-pub-7460743400720494~2228053495" android:value="ca-app-pub-7460743400720494~2228053495" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Config.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Power clicker!</name>
    <description>
        A clicker game.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        Soap master
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <gap:plugin name="phonegap-admob" source="npm" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~7.1.4" />
     <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
 <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" source="npm">
 <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="16.0.0" />
 </plugin>
</widget>
```

Код js

```js
var admobid = {};

// TODO: replace the following ad units with your own
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  admobid = { // for Android
    banner: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',//test id
    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712',// test id
    rewardvideo: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917',
  };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  admobid = { // for iOS
    banner: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716',
    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910',
    rewardvideo: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313',
  };
} else {
  admobid = { // for Windows Phone, deprecated
    banner: '',
    interstitial: '',
    rewardvideo: '',
  };
}

function initApp() {
  if (! AdMob ) { alert( 'admob plugin not ready' ); return; }

  // this will create a banner on startup
  AdMob.createBanner( {
    adId: admobid.banner,
    position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    isTesting: false, // TODO: remove this line when release
    overlap: true,
    offsetTopBar: false,
    bgColor: 'black'
  } );

  // this will load a full screen ad on startup
  AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
    adId: admobid.interstitial,
    isTesting: false, // TODO: remove this line when release
    autoShow: true
  });
}

if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
} else {
    initApp();
}
```

Результат:
[image: тестовые id]

При вводе моих id

[image: свои id]

Comment: По идее надо просто подождать. Очень часто рекламы нет в первые часы (реже дни) после добавления баннера

Comment: Спасибо, в таком случае будем ждать.